# How to convert this to lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, orika

```
factory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new CustomConverter<Source, Target>() {
    @Override
    public Integer convert(BigDecimal source, Type<? extends Integer> destinationType, MappingContext mappingContext) {
        return new Target(source.intval());
    }
});
```

How to convert this to lambda expression?

Comment: This shouldn't compile. Why is the return type `Integer`? And why is `source` a `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `CustomConverter` is an abstract class, not a functional interface. It's not even possible to create a generic instance that delegates to a lambda because it relies on [Gafter's Gadget](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) to capture the type arguments at runtime, which means it has to be subclassed with actual types.